# detached entity passed to persist with OneToMany entity which has composite PK

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Error:
`detached entity passed to persist: model.RoleClass`

I'm trying to persist a `WorkflowInstance` along with a list of `WorkflowPlayers` where the `WorkflowPlayer` entity has a composite primary key as such

```
public class WorkflowInstancePlayerId implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id")
private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "role_class_id", referencedColumnName = "role_class_id")
private RoleClass roleClass;
```

and its entity

```
@Entity
@IdClass(WorkflowInstancePlayerId.class)
public class WorkflowInstancePlayer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;
    @Id
    private RoleClass roleClass;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "badge", referencedColumnName = "badge")
    private Employee playerUser;
     ... other properties
```

The `RoleClass` and `WorkflowPlayers` list is initially determined based on a query to determine which roles a type of workflow requires and is setup with a jsf Prerender of the facelet page and done as follows:

```
private void setupInstancePlayers() {
    ArrayList<WorkflowInstancePlayer> temp = new ArrayList<WorkflowInstancePlayer>();
    for (WorkflowClassRole wcr : wfc.getRole_list()) {
        WorkflowInstancePlayer wfiPlayer = new WorkflowInstancePlayer();
        wfiPlayer.setRoleClass(wcr.getRoleClass());
        wfiPlayer.setRole_required(wcr.getRole_required());
        temp.add(wfiPlayer);
    }
    wfi.setPlayer_list(temp);
}
```

and the form is dynamically generated iterating over the player list. This workflow class called for Originator, Checker and Approver Roles.  (The Role Classes are already persisted)
[image]

On form submission I get said the error `detached entity passed to persist: model.RoleClass`

I don't want to persist a new role class just the id of the role class and workflow instance id

My workflow instance entity looks like

The WorkflowInstance Entity

```
@Entity
public class WorkflowInstance implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "trx_seq", sequenceName = "trx_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "trx_seq")
    private Long workflow_instance_id;

    private String product_instance_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workflowInstance")
    @OrderBy("step_num ASC")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<WorkflowInstanceWorkItem> work_item_list;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workflowInstance")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<WorkflowInstanceWorkItemAction> work_action_list;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<WorkflowInstancePlayer> player_list;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_class_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_class_id")
    private WorkflowClass workflowClass;
    ... other properties but probably not relevant
```

I've tried all sorts of cascading options jpa and hibernate.

Comment: Are you working with Spring MVC? If so make sure that you've properly mentioned that Spring will manage the transactional aspects of your application via the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` configuration.

Comment: No, I am not using Spring.

Comment: Have you tried reading in the roleClass from the persistence unit before using it to set references, or calling merge instead of persist?  Otherwise, you will need to find out where it is referenced from in your model, and how persist would get cascaded to it - the described model isn't clear, as WorkflowInstancePlayerId isn't an entity and you haven't shown the WorkflowInstancePlayer or what wfi.setPlayer_list does.

Comment: My situation is similar to a user wants to build a Sports Team and selects Football.  I query the SportsTeamType (WorkflowClass) and determine we need a list of Player Name (WorkFlowInstancePlayers) input boxes for QB, Running Back , etc. (RoleClass).  On submit, the Team Name instance (WorkFlowInstance) is persisted. The lists of players should also be persisted using the sequence from Team Id (workflowinstance id) and the Position Id (RoleClass Id).  The players position definition (QB) is already defined and shouldn't tried to be persisted again.